# Pattern.List validation regexp fails

Tags: java, regex, rest, spring-mvc

Got myself stuck in following problem: previously I had a single regexp to check MSISDN and it looked like this: (380)[0-9]{9}. It worked like a charm but change request came in and I had to split it into two parts - first to check if the string start with 380 and the second one to check if it contains only digits and contains 12 characters. For some reason it doesn't work and fails during test on totally valid MSISDN: 380671112233. I've tried googling thing like regexp which check strating characters ^ but all my experiments failed.  Can anybody suggest what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance!

```
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(InfoController.INFO_ENDPOINT )
public class InfoController {

public static final String INFO_ENDPOINT = "/info";
private final InfoService service;

@GetMapping(value = "/{msisdn}")
@ResponseBody
public InfoResponse getInfo(
        @Pattern.List({
                @Pattern(regexp = "(380)", message = "MSISDN_INCORRECT"),
                @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{12}", message = "MSISDN_OUT_OF_RANGE")
        })
        @PathVariable("msisdn") String msisdn,
        @RequestParam("cid") String cid) {
    log.info("[{}] get information for msisdn {}", cid, msisdn);
    InfoResponse response = service.getInfo(msisdn, cid);
    log.info("[{}] successful response for msisdn {} - {}", cid, msisdn, response);
    return response;
}

}
```

My test setup

```
private static final String CID = "123-aaa-bbb-312";
public static final String MSISDN = "380671122333";
public static final String NAME = "PP AA";
public static final long ID = 476561L;
public static final int DISTANCE = 69;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@MockBean
private InfoService service;

@Test
@DisplayName("Valid request. Expected: valid response")
public void testController1() throws Exception {
    InfoResponse response = new InfoResponse(MSISDN, NAME, ID, DISTANCE);
    when(service.getInfo(any(), any())).thenReturn(response);
    String request = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromPath(InfoController.INFO_ENDPOINT)
            .pathSegment(MSISDN)
            .queryParam("cid", CID)
            .build().toString();
    mockMvc.perform(get(request))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(content().json(
                    "{\"param1\":\"" + MSISDN + "\"" +
                            ",\"param2\":\"" + NAME + "\"" +
                            ",\"param3\":" + ID +
                            ",\"param4\":" + DISTANCE + "}"
            ))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Try `@Pattern(regexp = "380[0-9]*", message = "MSISDN_INCORRECT"), @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{12}", message = "MSISDN_OUT_OF_RANGE")`

Comment: no, didn't work. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Try step by step. Create another simple test, then match string against first regex, and then against second. Try various regex separately in that simple test. For instance, 380.* instead of (380). So on.